# Vim. Add * to the end of each word between slashes

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I have text:

```
alpha/beta/gamma
alpbeta/gamma
alpha/beta/gamma
This is an example.  Test1,Test2,Test3
alpha/beta/gamma
This is an example.
Test1,Test2,Test3
```

i want to add * to the end of each word between slashes (/), but vim don't found nothing by my pattern...

my command:

```
:%s/\/(.*?)\//*/g
```

result I want:

```
alpha/beta*/gamma
alpbeta/gamma
alpha/beta*/gamma
This is an example.  Test1,Test2,Test3
alpha/beta*/gamma
This is an example.
Test1,Test2,Test3
```

Comment: So, if your input is `a/b c d/ee fff/ g hh/` you want to obtain `a/b* c* d*/ee fff/ g* hh*/`? Could you please precise the requirements?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited my question and added preferred result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
:%s/\/[[:alpha:]]\+\ze\//&*/g
```

Or even

```
:%s/\/[^\/]*\ze\//&*/g
```

Here, the pattern is `\/[[:alpha:]]\+\ze\/`:

- `\/[[:alpha:]]\+` - The consuming part: `/` and then one or more letters
- `[^\/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `\ze\/` - end of the text consumed and then a `/` char must follow (as if it were a `(?=\/)` positive lookahead in common NFA regular expressions).

The replacement is `&` that stands for the whole match value and a `*` char.

The `g` flag  replaces all occurrences.

Comment: Using different delimiter could be of help here, e.g. `:%s#/[^/]*\zs#*&#g`

Answer (score 0):

According to your example it looks like you want a `*` before the last occurence of `/` in the line.

I'd go for recording a macro that does `$F/i*^VESCj` (where `^V` is <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> and `ESC` is <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

This means go to the end of the line, find the `/` backwards, enter insert mode, type the `*`, go back to normal mode, go down a line.

You can record this as a macro and play it back for the whole file with something like `:%normal @x` (if you recorded on `x`)

Answer (score -1):

Vim uses its own regular expressions dialect, where:

- the `*?` in `.*?` is meaningless,
- grouping parentheses must be escaped with backslashes,
- and various other differences with other dialects…

As it stands, your pattern would match:

- a slash, `\/`,
- followed by an opening parenthesis, `(`,
- followed by 0 or more of any character, `.*`,
- followed by a question mark, `?`,
- followed by a closing parenthesis `)`,
- followed by another slash, `\/`,

which is nowhere to be found in your sample.

See `:help perl-patterns`.

Comment: Thanks! I think i am close now, but new regex matches word WITH slashes, but I need to take word BETWEEN brackets.

New regex: \/.*\/